# Required parameter is missing: response_type

Tags: c#, rest, google-oauth, restsharp

We have created an authentication program(OAuth2/REST/C#/RestSharp 103.1.0.0).

We are refering to this URL( https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer )

Until now we had to use "ResponseUri" included in the response.

Since around August 21, the following error has occurred.

> Error: invalid_request
>   Required parameter is missing: response_type

As a result of investigation, this event could be resolved when we use `ResponseUri.OriginalString`.

Do I need to use the `ResponseUri.OriginalString` instead of `ResponseUri`?

Comment: This is for a website or an app?  What type of library are you using?

Comment: This is for a website.
We use the library that is RestSharp 103.1.0.0.